# Low voltage wiring of outside condenser & condensate pump

Tags: furnace

This is my 1st question here, hope someone can help quick since temperatures are rising. This past winter the cage on my furnace was making noise. It was the fan hitting the cage. I took it out and found it was loose and tighten it. To accomplish this I had to unwire those wires that were in the way of taking out the fan/cage. I labeled every wire and the heater worked fine and no more noise. Now, when I want to turn on the a/c, only the fan inside turns on. The condenser outside does not. I assume it's not getting the 24 volts. I traced the wires coming from the condenser outside and this is when I saw a loose wire that apparently I forgot when I took out the fan/cage. The problem is that I do not know where it goes to. Please look at the pictures provided.[image]

Aside from the outside condenser, there is also this pump. kinda tight in together.[image]

This last picture shows the loose wire. It comes from the pump wiring. See how it ties in with the condenser wiring from outside ( the other brown wire bundle). The question is, where to I tie in the white loose wire coming from the pump?

Answer (score 0):

Your picture doesn’t really show much. The screw terminals on the circuit board would be helpful. The wire going to the condensate pump is going to a high level cut off switch. Since you say everything else is working except the condensing unit I can assume it is cutting power to just the condensing unit. There is a low voltage wire coming from the condensing unit. One wire should be on Y and the other on C. If one wire is on Y then your missing wire goes on C or vise versa. Basically either the C or the Y wire was removed from the circuit board and wire nutted to the condensate pump wire. It goes through the switch and back to where the wire was removed.